# How to develop broadband router with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, application-development, mobile-broadband

I wanted to develop a router from scratch in Ubuntu which will manage following things.

1. User bandwidth Management.
2. User Browsing History and Bandwidth tracking.
3. Assign HotSpot, PPPoe type  of the connection.
4. Set various firewall rules.

Can you please guide me how can I do above things with Ubuntu?
I want to convert Ubuntu Server as a NAS for Broadband management and bill solutions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Traffic Control HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/)
2. [Squid Proxyserver Documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/)
3. [hotspot - chillispot](http://www.chillispot.info/) [Other hotspots](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot)
4. [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

and you can read the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)

Comment: Also consider **OpenWRT**, and running core functionality on the router instead.

Comment: As I understand it. He want to use PC platform. OpenWRT is good idea too. I have seedbox/file's trash with OpenWRT based on Tp-Link TL-WR1043ND.